# distance to a spline in Dreamteck.Splines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, distance, projection, spline

How can I calculate a gameobject's projection point on a spline in Dreamteck Splines tool? There are Project and CalculateProjection functions but there are void and don't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamteck has a SplineProjector script that should project to the percentage on the spline, and then you just need to evaluate its position (if you are trying to get the real world position).

```
double projectorPercent = splineProjector.GetPercent();
```